# Translation from Scala to Java

Tags: java, scala

I have this piece of code which was written in Scala:

```
pushArguments.par.foreach(
      recFilesToPush => push(recFilesToPush).par.foreach {
        case (subsId, pid, sid) =>
          println(s"\n ----------- FINISHED PUSHING -------------- \n sid = $sid \n pid = $pid & subsid = $subsId")
```

where push method implemented as follow:

```
def push(desiredPushArguments: List[PusherParams]): ParSeq[(Int, Int, Long)] = {
    desiredPushArguments.par.flatMap(
      x => {
        x.sessionStreamsDelayFromAuth = 0
        sendSessionAndReturnDetails(x)
      })
  }
```

I have started to translate it to java doing this:

```
pushArguments.add(new ArrayList<PusherParams>(Arrays.asList(pp)));
        pushArguments.parallelStream().forEach(argument->push(argument));
```

Now when I am stuck on the part where case got 3 values(subsId, pid, sid) which returning from push method which I translated to java (partial) this way:

```
public ParallelSequence push(List<PusherParams> desiredPusherArguments){

        System.out.println("Gaga");

     //   System.out.println(desiredPusherArguments.parallelStream().flatMap(x ->  desiredPusherArguments.stream()));
      //  System.out.println(desiredPusherArguments.parallelStream().flatMap(x -> {x.sessionStreamsDelayFromAuth,sendSeesionAndReturnDetails(x)} );


    }
```

where ParallelSequence is a class which hold three member varaiables : subsId, pid, sid

but it is not working as expected.

Answer (score 3):

I do not know what you are trying to do but two major problems with your java code

1. you write public `ParallelSequence` push, this means you expected to return `ParallelSqeuence` type which is not the case.
2. You are trying to print object, in this case you need to print each results and need to move print inside lambda expression.

So you can do following to get it run:

```
public void push(List<PusherParams> desiredPusherArguments){

    desiredPusherArguments.parallelStream()
            .flatMap(x -> desiredPusherArguments.stream())
            .forEach(i -> System.out.println(i.getSomProp()));

}
```

`getSomeProp` is just example and could be any property from your `PusherParams` class

Comment: public static ParrallelSequence push(List<PusherParams> desiredPusherArguments){
        System.out.println("Gaga");
        desiredPusherArguments.parallelStream().flatMap(x ->  desiredPusherArguments.stream());
        return desiredPusherArguments.parallelStream().flatMap(x -> {x.sessionStreamsDelayFromAuth,sendSeesionAndReturnDetails(x)};


    }

I am using this code but wanted to know if I will get the same effect as in scala code as for ParallelSequence is a class which will hold 3 variables (int, int, long) beacuse there is no equivalent in scala for ParSeq[(int, int, long) ]